# how to create/declare global variables in oozie?

Tags: hadoop, sqoop, oozie

I'm creating an oozie worklow where I need to have multiples shell actions but I'm facing the problem that for every shell action I have in my workflow I have to declare an environment variable meaning that if I have 10 shell actions I need to declare 10 times, my question is: if there's any way I can declare/create global variables in order to avoid duplicated variables that are doing the same?

Example:

```
    jon.properties
    oozie.use.system.libpath=true
    security_enabled=False
    dryrun=False
    nameNode=hdfs://localhost:8020
    user_name=test
    jobTracker=localhost::8032

<workflow-app name="My_Workflow" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.5">
<start to="shell-a0a5"/>
<kill name="Kill">
    <message>Error [${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
</kill>
<action name="shell-a0a5">
    <shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.1">
        <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
        <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
        <exec>script1.sh</exec>
        <file>/user/hive/script1.sh#script1.sh</file>
    </shell>
    <ok to="End"/>
    <error to="Kill"/>
</action>
<end name="End"/>
```

my script1.sh is expecting a parameter named as user_name which I have it declared into the job.properties but it's not working in my workflow I'm getting missing argument username

I would like to know how can i send parameters to a shell script from a global configuration file

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shortening Oozie workflows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24327264/shortening-oozie-workflows)

Comment: Thanks man but this is not working in my case, I was able to declare the variable but I'm not getting the value on the shell script

Comment: Can you provide the sample of what you have tried and mention what/where it is not working.

Comment: sample attached to the question. Thanks

Comment: I was able to resolve my problem, thanks you all.

Comment: That is great to hear. It would be great to post an answer for how to solved the issue. It will help the future users. Thanks.

Comment: Sure I will, I need to organize the code and I'll post the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to create global parameters in order to pass values as : user & password, HADOOP_USER_NAME (in my ase ) but I was able to figure it out using shell script, so within the shell I define the following parameters for my proposal:

```
export HADOOP_USER_NAME=admin;
connection=$(hdfs dfs -cat /user/connection.txt)
```

where the connection.txt contains all the information for the connection string
then using sqoop I pass the info in this way within the shell file:

```
sqoop $connection --table test --target-dir /user/hive/warehouse/Jeff.db/test/ --m 1 --delete-target-dir
```

and in this way I was able to resolve my problem, I had to declare some global variables but those were necessary to execute sqoop in parallel using &.

Answer (score 0):

passing global parameters to a shell action is not possible.
The globals section is only for properties. For more details see the answer for this question:
[OOZIE: properties defined in file referenced in global job-xml not visible in workflow.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38337362/oozie-properties-defined-in-file-referenced-in-global-job-xml-not-visible-in-wo)

To pass parameters/variables in a shell action you can either pass those values as *arguments* via the shell action (you can still declare them in your job.properties file:

```
<action name="shell-<name>">
  <shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.3">
    <exec>script1.sh</exec>
    <argument>${user_name}</argument>
    <argument>${database}</argument>
    <argument>${etc}</argument>
    <file>/user/hive/script1.sh#script1.sh</file>
  </shell>
    <ok to="End"/>
    <error to="Kill"/>    
</action>
```

In your shell script you than can call these variables like this:

```
#!/bin/bash -e
user_name=${1}
database=${2}
etc=${3}
<your shell commands>
```

and you can then use those variables in your shell script. You can also use just $1, $2, etc but for readability it's better to name your arguments first.

To prevent the passing of lots of arguments to each and every shell action you can also add a [config file](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/conffile) to your shell action, with all these parameters, and import that file in your actual shell script:

```
<action name="shell-<name>">
  <shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.3">
    <exec>script1.sh</exec>
    <file>/user/hive/script1.sh#script1.sh</file>
    <file>/user/hive/CONFIG_FILE</file>
  </shell>
    <ok to="End"/>
    <error to="Kill"/>    
</action>
```

shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
. CONFIG_FILE

<your shell commands>
```